# Not able to suspend or shutdown properly on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: suspend, shutdown, 17.10

I renctly updated to Ubuntu 17.10 and I'm not able to suspend my desktop. My screen are powered off but the fan still run and I'm not able to press the power button of my computer to resume.

I have this in `/var/log/syslog` :

```
Nov  3 04:35:57 oscar gnome-shell[3537]: JS WARNING: [/home/dougui/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/suspend-button@laserb/extension.js 202]: assignment to undeclared variable gnomeShellVersion
Nov  3 04:35:57 oscar NetworkManager[1050]: <info>  [1509698157.6376] manager: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Nov  3 04:35:57 oscar NetworkManager[1050]: <info>  [1509698157.6376] manager: sleeping...
Nov  3 04:35:57 oscar systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Nov  3 04:35:57 oscar org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2428]: Window manager warning: Failed to set power save mode for output DVI-I-1: Not permitted
Nov  3 04:35:57 oscar org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2428]: Window manager warning: Failed to set power save mode for output HDMI-1: Not permitted
Nov  3 04:35:57 oscar gnome-shell[2428]: Screen lock is locked down, not locking
Nov  3 04:35:57 oscar systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Nov  3 04:35:57 oscar systemd-sleep[5572]: Selected interface 'enp4s0'
Nov  3 04:35:57 oscar systemd-sleep[5572]: OK
Nov  3 04:35:57 oscar systemd-sleep[5572]: Suspending system...
```

I have errors but nothing special.

Here is information about my system :

```
Linux oscar 4.13.0-16-lowlatency #19-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Wed Oct 11 19:51:52 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

### EDIT

It happens when I shutdown also. When I shutdown, I have this trace :

```
Nov  5 12:35:55 oscar org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4021]: Window manager warning: CurrentTime used to choose focus window; focus window may not be correct.
Nov  5 12:35:55 oscar gsd-print-notif[4211]: Source ID 2 was not found when attempting to remove it
Nov  5 12:35:55 oscar systemd[3975]: Stopping D-Bus User Message Bus...
Nov  5 12:35:55 oscar kernel: [34246.603751] rfkill: input handler enabled
Nov  5 12:35:55 oscar systemd[1]: Stopping PackageKit Daemon...
Nov  5 12:35:55 oscar systemd[1]: Stopping Save/Restore Sound Card State...
Nov  5 12:35:55 oscar systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 129...
Nov  5 12:35:55 oscar org.a11y.atspi.Registry[2794]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":1024"
Nov  5 12:35:55 oscar org.a11y.atspi.Registry[2794]:       after 21 requests (21 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

Here is the result of `lspcu` :

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               58
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3570K CPU @ 3.40GHz
Stepping:            9
CPU MHz:             3403.445
CPU max MHz:         3800.0000
CPU min MHz:         1600.0000
BogoMIPS:            6806.89
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-3
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cpuid_fault epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
```

For `lspci` :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev c4)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 7 (rev c4)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 4-port SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 2-port SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde XT [Radeon HD 7770/8760 / R7 250X]
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series]
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 41)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
05:00.0 USB controller: Etron Technology, Inc. EJ168 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 01)
```

And results for`sudo lshw` are [here](https://gist.github.com/GCorbel/eab666ccb66ea1f35a538e7e0e1572ee) (Too long for SO).

Comment: What are your computer brand? I had HP Elitebook and I also have the same problem.

Comment: This is custom desktop.

Comment: What CPU, Graphics, and Chipset are you using? (`lscpu`, `lspci`, `sudo lshw`) Also I would recommend trying with as little plugged in as possible. (Try without excess USB devices, monitors, perhaps fancy gaming keyboards or other storage devices?)

Comment: Can you try booting a previous stable version of kernel from grub startup menu, check if the issue persists.

Comment: i had same problem with Arch once. I back to stable kernal fixed the issue.

Comment: @robobenklein I added some informations. I tried but it didn't worked.

Comment: @Legolas I tried with 4.10.0 but it's the same.

Comment: Ok, here's a weird idea: go to a Virtual TTY, Ctrl-Alt-F2, and stop the X server, `sudo service gdm stop`, then see if sudo poweroff works?

Comment: @robobenklein it's the same.

Comment: Does your BIOS have settings like S3 sleep modes?

Comment: @robobenklein I don't think it's a BIOS issue because it was working with Ubuntu 17.04. My mother board it a Gigabyte Z77 and I new saw this option.

Comment: Do you know if your ACPI support is working properly? What happens when you press the power button while the system is active? Perhaps you could try some different suspend modes, https://01.org/blogs/rzhang/2015/best-practice-debug-linux-suspend/hibernate-issues has a few good example commands you could try out.

Comment: When I press on the power button, it power off my computer without any warning from the OS. It's not what I set in the settings. I'm checking the link you gave.

Comment: suspending to idle and to RAM do the same problem. Suspending to disk is more strange. It start to suspend (close the screen) then it reopen the screen but I cannot use mouse or keyboard. Debug options seems to be more tricky and I don't have the time right now. I will check later.

Comment: I don't know why but it seems to work with `sudo sh -c "echo mem > /sys/power/state"`. I don't know why it didn't worked this morning. It works with `sudo sh -c "echo disk > /sys/power/state"` too. I just have to find how to change the default sleep mode for ubuntu. It didn't with `sudo sh -c "echo freeze > /sys/power/state"`.

Comment: I applied [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/05/ubuntu-16-04-shutdown-hibernate-your-laptop-lid-closed/) solution  and it works. The problem is no 100% solved but it's correct at the moment. You can add an answer and I will accept it. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Finally, doing `sudo sh -c "echo mem > /sys/power/state"` is the best solutions because hibernation does not always work. I changed the access to don't have to use root everytime, I created a shortcut and I placed it in my favorites. Now, it works. I just have to wait for a fix in a future version.

Answer (score 0):

I finally do this for a few months :

```
gksudo -k -u root "sh -c 'sync && echo 1 > /sys/power/pm_trace && pm-suspend'"
```

I created a shortcut.

I hope it will be solved in Ubuntu 18.04.